# What is the Dart & Flutter Development

Tags: flutter, dart, development-environment

Is Dart my only programming language option with Flutter or can I use other languages like C++, Java, Kotlin, or Go? What are all the available options for langugaes with the Flutter framework if they're are additional options.

Comment: Dart is the only option. You can integrate native Java/Kotlin or Objective-C/Swift code using platform channels, but that is just to call out to from Flutter. See also https://flutter.io/faq/#why-did-flutter-choose-to-use-dart

Comment: I agree with all the other answers, but wanted to add that I started working with Flutter a few weeks ago and found Dart a breeze to pick up (I have a C#/JavaScript/TypeScript background).

Answer (score 4):

**Dart** is the **only** programming language that is currently supported by the **Flutter** framework. You can [get started here](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/).

To be honest, I doubt that there are any plans on integrating other programming languages because *Flutter* is built around *Dart* and vise versa.

When writing applications in the framework, you can still access native code, that would be Android *(Java, Kotlin, C++)*, iOS *(Objective-C, Swift)* and probably other platforms in the future.